# Not the NSTimer or the applicationSignificantTimeChange then what do I use?

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsdate, nstimer

I want text to change once a day even if my app is not open at the time `NSTimer` doesn't run while your app is closed, `applicationSignificantTimeChange` won't get the message if my app is closed either.

What I need to do is.

(1) get the current date 
(2) choose a phrase based on the current date and 
(3) update your label

I still might use `NSTimer` or `applicationSignificantTimeChange` to handle the case where my app *is* open at midnight, but I need to get the phrase-picking method working first so my timer or time change method can call it at midnight for the new date

Can anyone help me out with this problem and what I need to do to make it work?

Comment: You should never need to update display elements while your app is closed.  Why not wait until it's opened, check the current time, and set your label accordingly?

Comment: I need a phrase to change everyday. Is there away for the app to update itself if I say want a phrase to change at midnight everyday? And if the user misses a couple of nights i need it to skip to the right phrase that its on.

Comment: Think of how you would write a website to do the same.  I doubt you keep a process running just to update a string every 12 hours.  Instead, you'd probably determine the correct phrase based on the current date and time.

Comment: so with each phrase i need to put the date and time it will change?

Comment: Look at the current time stamp and compute the correct phrase.

Answer (score 4):

I hope this code is good enough to stop all the similar questions you are asking way too often.
Yes, lesson for the future: bug me with a lot of questions in categories I'm interested in and I will deliver the code.

```
- (void)updateLabelForDate:(NSDate *)date {
    NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [date timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    NSInteger days = timeInterval / (60*60*24);
    NSArray *sloganArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            NSLocalizedString(@"Slogan for day 1", nil),
                            NSLocalizedString(@"Slogan for day 2", nil),
                            NSLocalizedString(@"Slogan for day 3", nil),
                            NSLocalizedString(@"I'll hope you'll get it", nil),
                            nil];
    NSInteger usedSloganIndex = (int)days % [sloganArray count];
    NSString *slogan = [sloganArray objectAtIndex:usedSloganIndex];
    NSLog(@"Slogan: %@", slogan);
}

- (void)applicationSignificantTimeChange:(UIApplication *)application {
    [self updateLabelForDate:[NSDate date]];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    [self.window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [self updateLabelForDate:[NSDate date]];
    // the following is there to prove that this code works.
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        NSLog(@"Date: %@", date);
        [self updateLabelForDate:date];
        date = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:(60*60*24)];
    }
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [self updateLabelForDate:[NSDate date]];
}
```

Comment: Which am I putting into the .h file and which goes into the .m? Also how do I connect it to the label in the Interface? Im sorry that I am annoying you with this. This is the last part I need and I am done.

Comment: At risk of being rude, you have two options: either request that someone write a complete app for you or study how to write apps and post specific technical questions.  This approach of asking piecemeal helps neither party.

Comment: Im familiar with java, just not moving through xcode. Again if its to much sorry for bothering you.

Comment: Then you're clearly experienced and capable.  Read up on ObjC and Cocoa paradigms.  Apple provides excellent documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't, if the application isn't running.

You can however use a "Local Notification" - which is sort of like a "Push Notification" - except it is sent by your own device - to tell you that the app needs attention. This can be scheduled.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Local notifications cannot trigger processing while the app is closed.  That requires user action.

Comment: Alright if Notifications can't work is there away for the app to update it self? Say i want a phrase to change at midnight every night, and the user misses a couple of days without activating the app. Can the App jump to the appropriate phrase for the day?